# What is the maximum RAM that I can install on my Dell Inspiron One 2320

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu, motherboard, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron One 2320 Machine whose owners manual officially states it can support a maximum of 8GB RAM. That information is also confirmed at the official Dell forum [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Desktops-General-Read-Only/Memory-upgrade-for-Inspiron-one-2320/td-p/4639317)

**My Computer Details**

**OS**
I am running Windows 10 Pro Version 1607 x64 bit.

**Processor**
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400S CPU @ 2.50GHz Code Name Sandy Bridge
[CPU Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH14k.png)

**Motherboard**
Dell Model 0XW3KG

**BIOS**
Dell A10 09/17/2012
[Motherboard + BIOS Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syqah.png)

**Memory**
2 x 4GB Kingston 800.0 MHz (DDR3-1600 / PC3-12800)
[RAM Slot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLuVa.png)
[RAM Slot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTkPS.png)

**Graphics Card**

Intel HD Graphics 2000 Sandy Bridge GT1 *and*
NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M GF108M

**Discrepancy**

Running this command in the terminal I get 32GB support

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic memphysical get maxcapacity
MaxCapacity
33554432 => 32 GB
```

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X0bf.png)

**Therefore I'm suspicious.**

I've scoured the internet and other super user questions and what I have gathered is that maximum ram capacity practically possible not only is dependent on the manufacturer's specification or output of the command but on various other factors like motherboard, processor etc therefore I have provided all the details above.

I cannot come to any conclusion based on my research.

I have not ordered any RAM hitherto but would love to upgrade if I can/possible because it is a definite need for me as I'm struggling with 8GB ( Hint -> I produce video content )

Please help.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: 16GB. I’m sitting in front of one with 16GB installed right now. It’s not officially supported but it’s working great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8 GB.

To get information about your Dell, find your Service Tag number (from the sticker, or the BIOS, or by running:

WMIC csproduct get vendor,name,identifyingnumber

Then put in the Service Tag at this site:

https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us?app=warranty

Sometimes I would recommend going with the motherboard manufacturer and motherboard model number, and checking for BIOS updates.  But being that DELL probably has their own custom motherboards, basically they are the motherboard manufacturer.

Besides what the manufacturer says, there are also other organizations that claim the 8 GB value:

https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/dell/inspiron-one-2320?wgu=2600_16644_16080150358703_ee736c0ca8&wgexpiry=1610607035&cm_mmc=affiliation-_-null-_-null-_-null

https://www.datamemorysystems.com/dms-memory/dell/inspiron-one-2320.htm

So even the places trying to sell memory say that 8 GB is the limit.

If there is a lesson to be learned here, it is: information from WMI is not always accurate.  It is most often an good indicator, especially with more modern systems (it was more questionable in the days when Windows XP was more common), but it doesn't completely surprise me that WMI might get some information from a driver/device but that information doesn't quite match a quite real physical limitation.